# XML Create and Use Variables-Maven

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, variables

I have a maven project where I have several jar files added as dependencies. Al these files are stored in the same location/directory, for instance: D:\project\lib.

**Sample**

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>D:\\Project\Lib\xyz-1.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>qwe</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>D:\\Project\Lib\qwe-1.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
.......
</dependencies>
```

**The Goal**

The goal is to save the lib folder path in a variable and use in systemPath for all dependencies like this:

```
<pathVariable>D:\\project\lib<pathVariable>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>&pathVariable;\xyz-1.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>qwe</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>&pathVariable;\qwe-1.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
.......
</dependencies>
```

**The Problem**

I'm not sure if this can be done in XML or the right syntax to declare, use and concat the variable with filename string in systemPath. I have searched for ways to use variables in XML but haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could in theory use external references like you describe in XML, but it's a bad idea for various reasons (not least of which are potential security implications). But luckily Maven already has the [concept of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696058/what-does-properties-tag-mean-in-pom-xml-maven) so you can just define your base path as a property and then use `${pathVariable}/xyz-1.jar` in your pom.

Comment: Do not use system-scoped dependencies... use a repository manager or deploy those jars into a repository....system-scope deps are platform specific... etc.